# How to add click event in ui-router link?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using angularjs and the ui-router. How can I fire a click-event in this jscode:

```
<a ng-if="item.external!==true" id="nav-drafts"
   class="standard-menu-item comm-icon-news" draggable="false"
   ui-sref="root.drafts.index" ui-sref-opts="{inherit: false}"
   href="#/drafts">
    <span class="icon sso-file"></span>
    <span class="menu-item-label" ng-bind-html="item.label">Edits</span>
</a>
```

How can I insert a click event inside the anchore passing in the ui-sref property?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider redirecting manually on click(`ng-click`) event handler

**HTML**

```
<a ng-if="item.external!==true" id="nav-drafts" 
   class="standard-menu-item comm-icon-news" draggable="false" 
   ng-click="navigate('root.drafts.index', {inherit: false})">
    <span class="icon sso-file"></span>
    <span class="menu-item-label" ng-bind-html="item.label">Edits</span>
</a>
```

**Controller**

```
navigate(stateName, params) {
   //do other stuff before redirecting
   $state.go(stateName, params); //call this for navigating to other state.
}
```